# Is it possible to show hard thresholding of a random vector only produces one vector?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, random

The hard thresholding operator $H_s(\mathbf{x})$ keeps the $s$ largest entries of $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in absolute values where $s < n$.
For example for $\mathbf{x}=[1,-3,1]^{\top}$, $H_2([1,-3,1]^{\top})$ is either $[0,-3,1]^{\top}$ or $[1,-3,0]^{\top}$. Therefore, in general, $H_s(\mathbf{x})$ is a set. However, when $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous random vector, $\mathbb{P}(x_i=x_j)=0$ for all $i \neq j$. This implies $H_s(\mathbf{x})$ is a singleton (only one vector) for any random vector $\mathbf{x}$.

**Question 1**

Am I right?

**Question 2**

If so, suppose $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, \dots,x_n]^{\top}$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $x_i \sim \mathcal{D}_i$ such that $\mathcal{D}_i$ is an unknow continuous distribution (if it helps we can assume $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i$) for all $i=1,\dots,n$). Can we show $H_s(\mathbf{x})$ is a singleton (only one vector)?

**Note**
This question asks whether we can order elements of a continuous random vector or not. Or, whether elements of a this random vector are always not equal.

Comment: For any fixed $n$, as long as $P(x_i = x_j) = 0 \,\, \forall i \neq j$, you can conclude that $Prob(|H_s(x)| = 1) = 1$, but you cannot say $|H_s(x)| = 1$ for any $x$.  Basically it is possible that $H_s(x)$ is not a singleton, but that event happens with probability $0$.  Does that make sense?  Do you really need a rigorous proof of this?

Comment: @antkam: My $n$ is fixed but I am not sure if $\mathbb{P}(x_i=x_j)=0$ when $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a random vector. That is the problem I am facing. I want to make sure whether I get your point, "I only can talk about the probability of the number of elements in $|H_s(x)|$, I cannot say anything about $|H_s(x)|$ itself, right?".

Comment: what do you mean by "no. of elements in $|H_s(x)|$"?  $H_s(x)$ is a set, but $|H_s(x)|$ is just a number which is the size of the set.  anyway, you can say $|H_s(x)| = 1$ with probability $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear up the terminology a bit.  $H_s(x)$ is a set, representing all possible results of the thresholding operation (for that specific $x$).  $|H_s(x)|$ is the size of that set, and $|H_s(x)| = 1$ means the set is a singleton.

**Claim:** If $\forall i \neq j: P(x_i = x_j) = 0$, then $P(|H_s(x)| = 1) = 1$.

**Proof:**

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
|H_s(x)| > 1 &\implies &\exists i \neq j: x_i = x_j 
\\
P(|H_s(x)| > 1) &\le &P(\exists i \neq j: x_i = x_j)
\\
 &= &P(\bigcup_{i \neq j} x_i = x_j)
\\
 &\le &\sum_{i \neq j} P(x_i = x_j) &\text{by union bound}
\\
 &= &0
\end{array}$$

---

So if your distributions $D_i$ meet the precondition that $\forall i \neq j: P(x_i = x_j) = 0$, then $H_s(x)$ is a singleton with probability $1$.

In particular, one way to meet the precondition is this: if all $D_i$ are independent, and if every $D_i$ has a CDF with no steps, i.e. its pdf has no "impulse", i.e. $\forall i, \forall v \in \mathbb{R}, P(x_i = v) = 0$.  The independence and the lack of impulse together meet the precondition, and so the claim holds and you can conclude $P(|H_s(x)|=1) = 1$.

Does this answer your question, or am I answering the wrong question? :)

Comment: can you clarify preconditions. I mean do you need both independence and no steps in the pdf or these are two different conditions that can be meet to get the result? Also, could you please answer my questions in the above comment section?

Comment: I think their above comment was simply illustrating the difference between "probability 0" and "does not occur" this specific expample is rather abstract, so consider the more familiar example, what is the probability of choosing the point 0.5 if you were to randomely choose a rational number between 0 and 1? It has probability 0 of course because there are infinitely many, but can you still choose a point? Of course, but whichever point you land on also had probability 0 of being landed on, and every point in the interval does, but this doesn't mean you can't choose a point